# Store constants in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, constants

I come from Java background. I was wondering if there was a way to have a class that stored constant values.

Specific to my problem, I was wondering if I could have something like:

```
@user.authentications.create(:uid => "12345", :provider => Provider::FACEBOOK)
```

where the Provider class stored all the static constants. Also, is this the right way to do it in Ruby on Rails?

**Extra Info:** 
I tried the above by having

```
class Provider
  FACEBOOK = "facebook"
  TWITTER = "twitter"
end
```

but it gave the error:

```
NameError:
       uninitialized constant Provider
```

Comment: Very similar questions already answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10607063/where-would-i-store-static-constant-values-in-a-rails-application/

Comment: the gist though is to put constants in the context that they are needed. In the specific class they are needed or inside of environment.rb if you need them everywhere.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10438647/declaring-static-properties-of-rails-model-subclasses/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1 (class variables):

```
class Provider
  @@FACEBOOK = "facebook"
  @@TWITTER = "twitter"
end

@user.authentications.create(:uid => "12345", :provider => Provider.FACEBOOK)
```

Using class variables is strongly discouraged though in some cases. A better way to go would be to use meta voodoo:

```
class Provider
  @FACEBOOK = "facebook"
  @TWITTER = "twitter"

  class << self
    attr_reader :FACEBOOK, :TWITTER
  end
end

@user.authentications.create(:uid => "12345", :provider => Provider.FACEBOOK)
```

Answer (score 0):

### If you would like to keep the implementation above

Try prefixing the `Provider::FACEBOOK` with a double colon

```
::Provider::FACEBOOK
```

This sets an absolute path so Ruby doesn't try to look for the constant inside of the current context/class/Controller. (My assumption is that right now it thinks the constant is defined in `UserController::Provider::FACEBOOK`)

### More Rails-esque

There have been a number of other posts on where to put constants, so please check out:

- [Declaring static properties of Rails model subclasses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10438647/declaring-static-properties-of-rails-model-subclasses/)
- [Where would I store static/constant values in a rails application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10607063/where-would-i-store-static-constant-values-in-a-rails-application/)

Basically, put constants where you actually need them. Either in the Controller/Model or in `environment.rb` if you want to access them everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare that class in your model file then it will be accessible. If you are declare in lib file then  you have add one line in your application.rb file

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```